# Python code to get ResourceStatus value in Lambda

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have setup CloudFormation to send notification events to SNS. The SNS topic recieves the below json message and it triggers the Lambda.
From the response I am unable to pick the value of **ResourceStatus** using the Python code in the Lambda.

```
{
  "Type" : "Notification",
  "MessageId" : "788eaf9c-59b0-51c6-a80d-fba3560",
  "TopicArn" : "arn:aws:sns:us-west-2:123456789123:topic2",
  "Subject" : "AWS CloudFormation Notification",
  "Message" : "StackId='arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:123456789123:stack/cfn-test1/1a907d80-d13c-11e8-89c4-503ac98d'\nTimestamp='2018-10-16T12:07:50.918Z'\nEventId='1a90f2b0-d13c-11e8-89c4-503ac98d'\nLogicalResourceId='cfn-test1'\nNamespace='123456789123'\nPhysicalResourceId='arn:aws:cloudformation:us-west-2:123456789123:stack/cfn-test1/1a907d80-d13c-11e8-89c4-503ac98d'\nPrincipalId='123456789123'\nResourceProperties='null'\nResourceStatus='CREATE_IN_PROGRESS'\nResourceStatusReason='User Initiated'\nResourceType='AWS::CloudFormation::Stack'\nStackName='cfn-test1'\nClientRequestToken='Console-CreateStack-482bccb9-1182-4a84-8d6c-bff2c33'\n",
  "Timestamp" : "2018-10-16T12:07:51.005Z"
}
```

The Python code I am trying is as below. I need to store the value like CREATE_IN_PROGRESS in status1 variable

```
import boto3
import json
import logging

logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))
    message2 = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message']
    print("Recieved Message: "+message2)

    try:
        if status1 == "CREATE_COMPLETE":
            print("Got Create in progress message")
        else:
            print("Nothing received")
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error( "An error occured: {}".format(e) )
    return message
```

Answer (score 3):

The information is coming through as newline-delimitered, so the elements first need to be split on `\n`, then parse out the `key, value` elements. Also, the values are in single quotes that need to be stripped.

The result is:

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    message = event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'].strip()

    dict = {k:v.strip('\'') for k,v in (x.split('=') for x in message.split('\n')) }
    print (dict['ResourceStatus'])
```

You'll get *lots* of messages coming through!

Comment: Awesome. Got the value exactly how I was looking for :)
Great Thanks